# Generate new 3D matrix from old 3D matrix with specific conditions

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate new `3D` matrix from old `3D` matrix then plot contour . The new matrix is the summation of slices depending on the step (summation add each 10 steps).

New matrix slice `1-10` will be the same as old matrix
slice `11` on new matrix will be slice `1+11` from old matrix
slice `12` on new matrix will be slice `2+12` from the old matrix and so on

when I reach slice `21` the new matrix slice `21` will be `1+11+21` slices from the old matrix 
slice `22` the new matrix slice `22` will be `2+12+22` slices from the old matrix and so on until I reach step `30`

when I reach slice `31` the new matrix slice `31` will be `1+11+21+31` slices from the old matrix and so on

After that, I am trying to plot contour for each slice. This mean I will have `50` contours plot

I used below code but it doesn't work correctly.

```
clc;
clear;
A=rand(20,20,50);
[m,n,k] = size(A); 
Total_A = reshape(cumsum(A,2),m,n,k);
[x,y]= meshgrid(linspace(0,2),linspace(0,2));
for ii=1:50
contour(x,y,Total_A(:,:,ii));
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

You can use the following approach:

```
mat  = int16(rand(10,10,50)*10); %initializes a random input matrix

%calculates the output matrix
outMat = mat;
for t=1:10
   outMat(:,:,t:10:end) = cumsum(mat(:,:,t:10:end),3);
end
```

Regarding to the contour part, you should change it as follows:

```
[x,y]= meshgrid(linspace(0,2,size(outMat,1)),linspace(0,2,size(outMat,2)));
for ii=1:size(outMat,3)
    figure,contour(x,y,outMat(:,:,ii));
end
```

**Results**

```
isequal(outMat(:,:,5),mat(:,:,5))
isequal(outMat(:,:,11),mat(:,:,1)+mat(:,:,11))
isequal(outMat(:,:,31),mat(:,:,1)+mat(:,:,11)+mat(:,:,21)+mat(:,:,31))

ans = 1
ans = 1
ans = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Please, the command for plotting contour not getting through.